# Combine all rows in a column where most rows are null

Tags: sql

I am writing a query trying to match true account IDs to incorrect account IDs across two tables using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  p.visitor_id,
  CASE WHEN p.visitor_id = c.username then accountId else null end as correct_account_id,
  CASE WHEN c.accountId is null then p.account_id else null end as incorrect_account_id
FROM `a_table` p
LEFT JOIN `another_table` c
  ON p.account_id = c.accountID
```

and am getting this result (single vistor_id subset):

| visitor_id | correct_account_id | incorrect_account_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | id |
| 1 | id | null |
| 1 | null | null |

I would like to create one row per visitor_id where there are no null values and just the two ids are listed.

Comment: Visitor ID should be 1,1,1 dont know how to fix that here sorry

Comment: What DBMS is this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
SELECT p.visitor_id, 
 MAX(CASE WHEN p.visitor_id = c.username then accountId else null end) as correct_account_id, 
 MAX(CASE WHEN c.accountId is null then p.account_id else null end) as incorrect_account_id 
FROM a_table p LEFT JOIN another_table c ON p.account_id = c.accountID
GROUP BY p.visitor_id
```

I removed the `distinct` and added the `group by`. `Group by p.visitor_id` means you want one row per visitor_id.

I wrapped your two `CASE` statements in `MAX` which means we want the maximum value (within the visitor_id grouping) there. Depending on your DB, you might need `MIN` instead (some DBs order nulls after other values by default, some order nulls after other values by default). Either way, the intention here is to find a non-null value for the column.

The big assumption here is that for each visitor_id, you have at most one correct_account_id and at most one incorrect_account_id that you care about. If you have more than one for the same visitor_id, this will only get one of them (the max/min). (Given that you explicitly say you want one row per visitor_id, this seems like a safe assumption.)